# hasClass Dynamic variable not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote the below code but it won't work. Kindly advice

```
<ul>
     <li><a href="#tab_1" data-toggle="tab">DANCE</a>
    <li><a href="#tab_1" data-toggle="tab">ABOUT</a>
</ul>

<a href="#" cta-view-action="tabs:previewBtn" class="white-link globalPreview ABOUT" style="display: none;">Preview</a>
```

---

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function (e) {
  if($('.globalPreview').hasClass($(this).text())){
     $('.globalPreview').show();
  }
});
```

here is the jsfiddle of this working code

[Demo Working Code](https://jsfiddle.net/qe2bq610/)

Comment: Can you show the element which invokes the click event here? Or kind of demo for your problem would be more helpful to answer. http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: make sure $(this) inside your function points to the element you think it does.

Comment: Have you checked on `$this` when invoking your function? What is its value or the object it is pointing to?

Comment: In what way does it not work? What is it that you expect to happen? Have you checked for errors in the console? No element you posted has a "data-toggle" attribute.

Comment: @gopinath it's working as per i understand so please tell us in which way it's not working..?

Answer (score 0):

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gujabogve/o1u64grk/)

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]')
```

change to

```
$('a[href^="#tab"]')
```